# when i try to use npm i apify command i get 243 error

Tags: web, web-crawler, screen-scraping

```sh
-Latitude-E7240:~/apifyScraper$ npm i apify
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 243
npm ERR! path /home/susant/apifyScraper/node_modules/better-sqlite3-with-prebuilds
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || npm run build-release

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/susant/.npm/_logs/2021-03-01T01_25_15_665Z-debug.log
```

Hear's a link to the log file :- https://pastebin.pl/view/ea337a13

Comment: Add the contents of `/home/susant/.npm/_logs/2021-03-01T01_25_15_665Z-debug.log` also to the question

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to node version 10 from 12 solved the issue for me. I am on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This is a workaround. Nobody has a solution?

Comment: Solved for me: In my case the problem was that npm was started with a user that does not have a home directory. This probably happened in upgrade from 16.15.0 to 16.15.1. I read somewhere. Node wants to create cache or something similar in there. When changed to start with a different user that has a home directory, everything worked again.